# Create aliases for layout content in android xml files

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I've created a class inherit from TextView so now when I have to use I implement:

```
<cdz.chapitreUn.preums.BoldTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        tools:context=".PreumsActivity" />
```

On the xml file. The thing Is It is a very long syntax to include the path of the class, Is there anyway (aliases or something else) I could write only:

```
<BoldTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        tools:context=".PreumsActivity" />
```

Thank you